# Pointer Problems in Vector

Tags: c++

I trying to brush up on my C++ since as it has been a while since I used it and I'm having a problem with storing pointers.  At the end of the method below, the vector "graph" has all of the vertices I inserts, but the edges that were supposed to be added are corrupt (I can see the edges in the debugger, but their data is garbage).  I was wondering if someone could help guide?

Thanks!

For reference, the add_edge function is declared as follows:

```
std::vector<vertice*> m_edges;
    ...
    ...
void add_edge(vertice* n);
{
    m_edges.push_back(n);
}
```

The primary problem:

```
std::vector<vertice> graph;
std::string line;

//Iterate over line
int lineCount = 0;
while(getline(file, line))
{
    auto vertices = parse_line(line);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vertices.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto result = std::find_if(
            graph.begin(),
            graph.end(),
            [&] (vertice cVert) { return cVert.getName() == vertices.at(i); });

        std::vector<vertice>::size_type currPos = 
            std::distance(graph.begin(), result);

        if(result == graph.end())
        {
            graph.emplace_back(vertice{vertices.at(i)});
        }

        if(i == 0) { continue; }
        graph.at(lineCount).add_edge(currPos == graph.size() ? 
            &graph.back() : &graph.at(currPos));
    }

    ++lineCount;
}

//The vector graph has corrupt nodes here
```

Comment: FYI, the singular of "vertices" is "vertex".

Comment: While not helpful to my particular issue, thank you for pointing that out.  I feel very silly.

Comment: I'm just glad you didn't take offense. I've seen this same thing many times in code or documentation; it never does any serious harm but it always triggers an urge in me to play grammar police, and here we have this all-too-convenient "add comment" button.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers to the content of a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) may be invalidated when you insert new elements, such as in [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

Consider [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to reserve a capacity before needing to reallocate the elements or use different container, one which does not invalidate references on insert, perhaps [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
auto v = currPos == graph.size() ? &graph.back() : &graph.at(currPos);
```

You are taking the address of the `graph` elements, however if (when) your `graph` vector resizes during the `emplace_back`, you end up with dangling pointers. A solution is to fix the size of the vector and instead of `push_back`/`emplace_back`, to use directly `std::vector::operator[]`, or to reserve enough memory via `std::vector::reserve`.

Probably unrelated:

```
graph.emplace_back(vertice{vertices.at(i)});
```

should just be

```
graph.emplace_back(vertices.at(i));
```

as otherwise you are invoking a copy constructor, [see the definition of `std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Comment: Even if I combine those lines so that it reads, I'll still get the same error, right? graph.at(lineCount).add_edge(currPos == graph.size() ? &graph.back() : &graph.at(currPos));